# Tailscale- Connection issues to access shared folders on my linux server

Tags: linux, tailscale

I installed Tailscale on my Linux Ubuntu server 20.04 some time ago. I also set a Route on it to access other devices in my LAN. Everything seems to work properly and I can access a few services running on my server via my smartphone browser by using their own LAN IPs and ports. Great!

I would also have liked to acces my shared folders I set on my linux server via my smartphone’s file manager as I did when I used to run Wireguard only, but after I entered my credential and my Server’s IP - where the shared folders lie - and pushed “Connect”, I got a Connection issue message. I haven’t yet figured out what the problem might possibly be?
For the record, I tried to disable the firewall on my linux server, but nothing changed, same issue.
Strangely, I can ping all of them from any devices:

Smartphone->linux machine

linux machine->smartphone

smartphone->Windows machines

Could you please help me?

Comment: Have you looked at a packet capture? Does the server at least receive your smartphone's connect attempts? Does it respond to them? (Does it respond through the correct interface?)

Comment: @user1686 Good Idea! I ran, sudo tcpdump -n port 445 on the linux machine. I can see traffic coming from other devices in my LAN, but if I connected  via Tailscale from my smartphone there is no traffic on port 445 captured telated to it. Of course, if the smartphone is connected via wifi to my LAN the access to the shared folders is granted. Thanks

Comment: @user1686 I also found out that I can get access to my shared folders on my server via SFTP. Still not able to do the same via SAMBA though. Strange.

Comment: You're capturing on the correct interface (eth0 vs tailscale0), right? Does the same occur if you try to access the server by its Tailscale address and its LAN address?

Comment: @user1686. I ran the command with only the port 445. Doesn't it scan all the interfaces available on the machine? and yes, the same occurs either I try to access the shared folders by the Taiscale address or its LAN IP address.

Comment: No, unless you use `-i any` – by default tcpdump chooses the first non-loopback interface on the system, i.e. typically `eth0` (it usually mentions this in the beginning of the output).

Comment: @user1686 ok. I ran the command sudo tcpdump -n port 445 -i any. Same. No clues of any connection attempts from my smartphone

Comment: @user1686 Another thing. When I used the file manager app on my smartphone to connect via SFTP, I saw the servers available to which I could connect before starting the connection setup. When I tried to do the same via samba, I didn't see any server available in the list as if the linux server IP wasn't advertised, as if it didn't exist at all. Thanks